# Does the term "Ethereum ECDSA signature" have a consistent meaning?

Tags: web3js, signature, cryptography

If you were writing some instructions and one of them was:

> Provide the Ethereum ECDSA signature of the file using the person's
> Ethereum address.

Would the above instruction have a consistent meaning (i.e. always produces the same output for a given file and address)? I ask because there appears to be [subtly different](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25610/820) [implementations](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/35425/820).

If not, what wording could you use to give it a consistent meaning? Perhaps with reference to EIPs...

Comment: https://medium.com/dac-technology-blog/ethereum-signatures-and-transactions-using-a-hardware-wallet-10a88f344caf

Comment: Until I can write a better answer, that Medium article has a big hole by not describing the prefix "\x19Ethereum Signed Message" (EIP 191).  The prefix is critical, for example https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/555  Ethereum users should not be signing anything without the prefix.

Comment: https://github.com/danfinlay/js-eth-personal-sign-examples/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I used:

> Provide the prefixed Ethereum ECDSA signature* of the hex encoded file using the
> person's Ethereum address.
>
> *As per `sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + dataToSign.length + dataToSign)))` (e.g. `web3.personal.sign`)

I think just using "Ethereum ECDSA signature" leaves ambiguity between above and the un-prefixed signature which is considered risky (for reasons I'm unsure of atm).

Comment: Yes, those additional details you provided is much better. Also, welcome back! (Did not recognize your username immediately.)